# Why did this flight, that usually flies around 40,000ft only fly at around 29,000ft for the route?

Tags: aircraft-performance, weather, altitude, boeing-787

Looking at the flight BY6272 BRS-PMI, it was considerably delayed and flew (according to the flight radar app) at 29,000 feet rather than its usual 40,000 for this same route. It is a Boeing 787 Dreamliner. Flight time is usually around an average of 2hours.

This flight is weekly. Why would it fly low on some weeks and high on others?

July 12, 2022: [image]

June 28, 2022: [image]

Comment: It sounds as though the airplane was not RVSM capable for some unknown system failure.

Comment: RVSM starts at 290.  If you're non RVSM, you're stuck below that.

Comment: I’d be hard-pressed to think this is an RVSM issue considering A/C in question is a B-787.  It would seem this is more up to the individual airlines flight planning dept. for routing weather, scheduling, etc.

Comment: How have you determined that this flight's normal altitude for this route is FL400?

Comment: Just spitballing... is 290 a limit for any MEL's on the 787?  Like pressurization, maybe? (Flying with 1 pack deferred on the 737 limits us to 250; dunno if the Dreamliner might have a slightly higher limit due to differences in their systems.)

Comment: Failure of the one of the ADC systems will preclude flight inside RVSM airspace.  Part 91 appendix G has other equipment that will preclude flight inside that airspace.  If the flight was originally cleared higher but then decided to stay at FL290, a failure like this is the most likely cause.

Comment: @wbeard52 if the airplane is at FL 290 it's already in RVSM airspace. It would have to be at or below FL 280 to be outside of RVSM airspace.

Comment: @757toga.  I would agree with you.  ATC can suspend RVSM separation at any altitude.  I would imagine ATC allowed the airplane to be there at the lowest altitude.  No one here really knows why the flight was flown so low.  It is all speculation.

Comment: Do we know winds aloft or other weather factor?  Possibly a speed benefit (looks like it was going faster) to make up for the delay that was mentioned?

Comment: I just checked FlightRadar24 for this same Flight ( BY6272, Bristol to Mallorca) that occurred on July 12th. It climbed to FL290 only (different  than shown in the OP's question) . Perhaps that is it's typical cruise altitude for this route. The OP has not provided any info indicating that this flight's normal cruise altitude is FL400. I'm voting to close the question.

Comment: @757toga I agree that the image in the question for 12 July (added by tedder42) is wrong (probably from another date). However, [on 5 July the flight climbed to FL430](https://uk.flightaware.com/live/flight/TOM6272/history/20220705/0630Z/EGGD/LEPA). It's perfectly obvious that FL290 is well below any reasonable cruise altitude for a 787, regardless of what the typical cruise altitude of this flight is. Voting to leave open.